# How to add stock alert notification when for items on the wishlist?

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, wishlist, out-of-stock

I want to add product alert notification when the product is out of stock on the Magento wishlist page, For this task, I need product ID how we get out of stock product ID?

Comment: Please add your magento version and provide what you have done

Answer (score 0):

In M1 you can get the stock of a product like this, where `$_product` is your product object `$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');`:

`$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);`

Comment: When I add out of product to wishlist , On customer's wishlist product out of product's detail in not showing I need out of stock product's detail on customer's wishlist.